# React page won't stop refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vps

I recently deployed my site on to a work test server. When I was building everything locally it seemed to be working fine. However once I went ahead and deployed it, the site now auto refreshes none stop almost every second. I have gone through my code and the small changes I made and can't seem to find what the cause of the issue is and why the site on our work vps is now refreshing over and over again. I'm hoping someone might have some insight on this. I have gone ahead and posted my App.jsx, index.js, and Home.jsx below. Any insight on the matter would be really appreciated.

I should also note that I went back and moved everything back local to see if there is something I might have done before sending it to the server. It would seem when I run this locally there are zero issues. I've also tested this on multiple browsers and asked a few colleagues to take a look and it seems it continues to refresh every second for them too and on multiple browsers

App.jsx

```
import "./app.scss";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Register from "./pages/register/Register";
import Watch from "./pages/watch/Watch";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/authContext/AuthContext";

const App = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          {user ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/register" />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          {!user ? <Register /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">{!user ? <Login /> : <Redirect to="/" />}</Route>
        {user && (
          <>
            <Route path="/movies">
              <Home type="movie" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/series">
              <Home type="series" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/watch">
              <Watch />
            </Route>
          </>
        )}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./context/authContext/AuthContext";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Home.jsx

```
import Navbar from "../../components/navbar/Navbar";
import Featured from "../../components/featured/Featured";
import "./home.scss";
import List from "../../components/list/List";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Home = ({ type }) => {
  const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState(null);
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getRandomLists = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axiosInstance.get(
          `lists${type ? "?type=" + type : ""}${
            genre ? "&genre=" + genre : ""
          }`,
          {
            headers: {
              token:
                "Bearer " +
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).accessToken,
            },
          }
        );
        setLists(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getRandomLists();
  }, [type, genre, axiosInstance]);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <Navbar />
      <Featured type={type} setGenre={setGenre} />
      {lists.map((list) => (
        <List list={list} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new axiosInstance is created on every render, and it triggers useEffect change.

Move the axiosInstance creation out of the component.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
});

const Home = ({ type }) => {
    const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
    const [genre, setGenre] = useState(null);
    // stuff
};
```

Comment: but why is axiosInstance in useEffect dependency ? if you just want an api call on mount just use empty array

Comment: It's still bad practice to create new instances on every render loop. A good linter yells at you for having undeclared dependencies, because doing that will lead to really hard-to debug problems.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I can't believe I didn't notice it. It would seem even esLint tried to tell me and show how I ended up ignoring. Thanks again for the suggestion on this

Answer (score 0):

Does the route that contains the  component refreshes infinitely?
That is because React Refresh causes component remount each time the state changes. In your case, you are creating an axios instance 1) not only **not storing it** in the useState ( you create it as a plain variable ), 2) but also on each  component render;

That causes the React Refresh to go crazy. The reason why it works on local might be related to some Webpack stuff, but that doesn't matter much as you should configure axios differently anyways.

Solution:

Why not to set up default configuration that will be common for all the requests through the application?

```
import "./app.scss";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Register from "./pages/register/Register";
import Watch from "./pages/watch/Watch";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/authContext/AuthContext";

const App = () => {
  useEffect( () => {
    axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
  }, [] )
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          {user ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/register" />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          {!user ? <Register /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">{!user ? <Login /> : <Redirect to="/" />}</Route>
        {user && (
          <>
            <Route path="/movies">
              <Home type="movie" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/series">
              <Home type="series" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/watch">
              <Watch />
            </Route>
          </>
        )}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

So that no instances are created, and defaults are configured correctly.

Then you use it like:

```
axios.post( '/someendpoint', { test : true } )
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: In Home.jsx would I use axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.API_URL }) still? Sorry still pretty new with React and trying to learn

Comment: Hi! axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.API_URL }) creates a new instance, we can avoid creating new instances and updating the state just setting the deafults on the axios object instead, like axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;